# Is there a "gas penalty" for using too many asserts in a contract?

Tags: solidity, gas, remix, optimization, compiler

I'm at a very puzzling scenario.

While using Remix, I noticed that adding a few `assert`s has caused a significant increase in execution cost (from ~50K to ~59K). And not only did it increase the execution cost of the updated function, but also of any other (public) function!!!

The only solid conclusion that I came up with, is that there's a "gas penalty" which takes effect as soon as the global number of `assert`s in the contract exceeds a certain threshold. BTW, the exact same behavior occurs when I replace the `assert`s with `require`s.

My current Solidity version is 0.4.16+commit.d7661dd9.Emscripten.clang, and I am compiling with optimization enabled. However, it seems to happen on previous compiler versions as well (I've tried a few of them, down to v0.4.11).

Unfortunately, I am unable to reproduce this problem within a minimal working code snippet, and pasting the entire contract here would probably mess up the entire question. So if possible to get an answer (or any other suggestion regarding the source of this problem) without a coding example, then I would be grateful.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Could you share the code in a github gist?

Comment: @maurelian: How do I do that (i.e., what's "github gist")? Thanks.

Comment: Are your asserts causing a big increase in gas in a loop by any chance? Or called by something in a loop.

Comment: @lungj: No, certainly not. That would be too easy if it had been the case. Though, I've now realized that it could possibly be an addition of any (arbitrary) piece of code. It's just that I was focused on those asserts, and it kinda eluded me that it might be any other opcode. In any case, the problem of one function's execution cost increasing after adding code in another function - this problem sustains. I can't find any way to explain this other than "caching" issues, which I sincerely doubt could even exist on the EVM.

Comment: @goodvibration I didn't entirely follow your last comment, but are your `assert`s using expensive operations like calling function as part of the `assert`?

Comment: @lungj: No, just asserting that a variable is smaller than some constant. In any case, I should rephrase this question. I get the same problem just by adding a couple of "meaningless" `if`s instead of `assert`s. With regards to the part of my description that you did not understand - note that in my question I emphasize the fact that adding code in one function has effected the execution cost of another function. This fact leads me to think that the "penalty" is possibly due to code size or something similar. Could that be the case here? Thank you.

Comment: Sharing the actual examples would be helpful. Are you possibly loading variables from storage in the assertions? That can get expensive pretty quickly.